# How to change the Windows User Identity globally for SQL connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, linq

Is there a way to replace the User identification globally in a SQL connection?

I have an application that must access multiple databases, the problem is that they are in 2 different domains. I am able to connect to the databases and the windows impersonation works without a problem. The problem is having to duplicate the impersonation statements before each call to the database. Is there a way I can set the SQL Windows Authentication once and allow it to persist through all the subsequent connections? BTW I am using Linq to Sql on a Windows application (WPF) and not a web application.

If clarification is needed for anything, please let me know.

Comment: Been a while since I was a system person but can you set up a domain trust to so that at SQL your account in the other domain is authorized.  Or you could use a linked server on your domain but then you route through the linked server.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do either of those. I thought about that but got denied by the network group. I have to do it all via code :(